# how to handle DOM in PHP

Tags: php, dom

My PHP code

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($file);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tags = $xpath->query('//div[@class="text"]');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->textContent;
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is to get the content of the div that has class 'text' but the problem when I loop and echo the results I only get the text I can't get the HTML code with images and all the HTML tags like p, br, img... etc i tried to use `$tag->nodeValue;` but also nothing worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I like [Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

```
include "lib.simple_html_dom.php"

$html = str_get_html($file);
foreach($html->find('div.text') as $e){
  echo $e->innertext;
}
```

Pretty simple, huh? It accommodates selectors like jQuery :)

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is create a temporary document, add the element to that and then use `saveHTML()`:

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
  $doc = new DOMDocument;
  $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($tag, true));
  $html = $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this snippet at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php:

```
<?php
function getInnerHTML($Node)
{
     $Body = $Node->ownerDocument->documentElement->firstChild->firstChild;
     $Document = new DOMDocument();    
     $Document->appendChild($Document->importNode($Body,true));
     return $Document->saveHTML();
}
?>
```

Not sure if it works though.